# How extract the element, id's and classes from a DOM node element to a string

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how I can extract the DOM tree string from an element.

Supposing I have this HTML structure:

```html
<div>
    <ul id="unordered">
        <li class="list item">Some Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When running the outerHTML (or equivalent) and extracting the tag, id's and classes:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item')[0].outerHTML;
//then extracting what I need

//it should output...
'li.list.item'
```

or

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#unordered')[0].outerHTML;
...

//it should output...
'ul#unordered'
```

Basically, it's the DOM tree representation of the element.

Also, feel free to suggest a better alternative that outerHTML

Thank you for your time

Comment: With all present attributes or just `id` and `class`?

Comment: why are you using the method querySelectorAll to get the reference of a unique id attribute?

Comment: Are you asking for the CSS selector representation of the element? I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a small work around this, Hope this helps, Not sure if this is the best approach but works.

**Note:** This will return the all the attributes values, Make sure you change this logic to get your result

```js
function getAttrs(identifier) {
  if (!identifier) return
  const element = document.querySelector(identifier)
  if (element) {
    let output = element.localName
    for (const attr in element.attributes) {
      if (element.attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        const attribute = element.attributes[attr]
        if (attribute.localName === 'id') {
          output += '#' + attribute.value
        } else if (attribute.localName === 'class') {
          output += '.' + attribute.value.replace(/ /g, '.')
        }
      }
    }
    return output
  }
}

console.log(getAttrs('.list'))
console.log(getAttrs('#unordered'))
```

```html
<div>
    <ul id="unordered">
        <li class="list item">Some Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I quite like this approach, I haven't tested it so far, but I can see it looks like what I'm after, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

[DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) have properties you can access

- `element.nodeName.toLowerCase()` would give you the tag
- `element.id` would give you the `id`
- `element.className` would give you the classes
- `element.attributes` would give you attributes
- `element.dataset` would give you data attributes

You can work with those to format the desired selector string